# Node JS based service on ECS fills 6.8GB disk space on error

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, amazon-ecs

I am using puppeteer in node project. In some specific scenery puppeteer page error occurs.
When that error occurs, ECS disk space get filled(6.8GB). For a few such kind of error ECS service stops due to no space left on device.

I am cleaning everything thing that i store in the file system.

This whole disk space jump occurs whithin 1minitue.

Some investigation shows that storage jump occurred inside my app folder.

I have another ECS service running same app, if the same thing happens on the other service, that doesn't fills disk space.

I have tried deploying same image to both services for one service disk space get filled for the other service this doesn't happen.

I am really stuck here, any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried to replicate that same error in my local docker, when error occurs storage doesn't get filled.

Comment: Are you deploying to EC2 or Fargate? Is it the EC2 EBS volume that's getting filled? If you know the space is being taken up inside your app folder, you should be able to use ecs exec https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html to look inside the file system and see exactly what files are getting created. You're going to have to do some debugging like that to determine exactly what files are getting created before you or anyone on here will be able to determine a solution.

Comment: Deploying to fargate. Looking into aws exec.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello Mark, we are deploying to fargate, i am not understanding why 2 different service is behaving so different. I have tried deploying second service using same image but similar storage fill event occurs for one service but other service is fine.